# Spring roo - few doubts - JAX-RS, removal

Tags: spring-roo

I am evaluating spring roo for one of our development project. Can someone help me know whether my understanding is correct ?

1. Spring ROO has JAX-RS implementation.
2. If spring roo is removed from the project , but still the dependencies will exist . POM file not be changed automatically.

I am new to spring roo any code/config example will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the first part of your question, but I can hopefully shed light on the second part.  If you remove Roo, you will be left with all the dependencies.  The POM is not updated, as the dependencies are still there.  Just because you tell Roo to stop managing your project and such doesn't mean you no longer need AspectJ.  The only way to remove the dependency would be to manually remove it.

Depending on the dependency you are trying to dissolve the task of removing it could be easy or hard.  For instance, AspectJ is used all over the place, and would probably be very hard to remove.  However, you may not be using JSON at all, and can easily remove Jackson with no problems.  It will highly depend on what your application is doing.  Keep in mind, Roo is nothing more than a very sophisticated macro tool.  It's not inventing a new way of doing anything, it is merely providing a means to generate boiler plate code that you can (and often do) generate on your own.  It just tends to do the boiler plate code in fancy ways so that it can maintain the code it generates without stepping on what you, as the developer, add in.